# How to find distinct records in vespa.ai?

Tags: vespa

We have a use case where we need to find out the distinct (unique) records.

We have 5 different keys in a document they are all searchable, need to find the distinct records using one key.

I also need to implement pagination on that distinct records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/grouping.html. The Vespa grouping language also supports pagination.

Example:

```
select ... | all(group(key) max(10) each( max(3) each(output(summary()))))
```

Will group hits by the key field, display at max 10 unique key values and for each unique key value render 3 best hits. Groups are by default ordered by the max relevancy of a hit in the group. When using max() you'll be able to paginate using the continuation parameter to fetch more groups or more hits.